# Modify Value of Parameters of Request

Tags: symfony

I want to know if it is possible to modify the value of the parameter of the request.

But i don't know how to do this.

I try with

```
$requestContent = $this->getRequest()->request->get('tactill_customerbundle_customertype');
```

Next I use

```
$request->request->replace()
```

But I don't how to use this method in my case.

Thanks

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The `replace` method replaces **all** of the parameters in the request, so you probably do not want to do that.

I would use the `set` method instead - So you can do:

```
$request->request->set('tactill_customerbundle_customertype', $newValue)
```

You can read more in the Symfony2 documentation (http://api.symfony.com/2.0/) - you are looking for `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request` (which is the `$request` variable), which then returns a `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag` when you call the `request()` method.

Comment: Using ````replace()````:

````$all = $request->request->all();
$all['tactill_customerbundle_customertype'] = $newValue;
$request->request->replace($all);```` This allow modify array parameters.